# Allow repetitions in this permutations generator

Tags: c++, cartesian-product

I have the following permutations generator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::cout;

void comb(string sofar, string rest, int n)
{
    std::cout << "comb('" << sofar << "', '" << rest << "', " << n << ")\n";
    string substring;

    if (n == 0)
        cout << sofar << '\n';
    else {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rest.length(); i++) {
            substring = rest.substr(0, i) + rest.substr(i + 1, rest.length());
            comb(sofar + rest[i], substring, n - 1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    comb("", "abcde", 3);

    return 0;
}
```

How could I adjust it to allow for repeated elements?
Example, permutations for options "abcde" could allow permutations like the following:

aab

aaa

acc

Comment: Just pass `rest` instead of `substring` in the recursive step.

Comment: Those are no longer permutations. What they are, effectively is k-digit base size(alphabet) numbers, which can easily be iterated by adding 1 at each step.

Comment: combinations not the same cartesian-product

Answer (score 0):

You may use following for cartesian_product

```
bool increase(const std::string& s, std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0, size = it.size(); i != size; ++i) {
        const std::size_t index = size - 1 - i;
        ++it[index];
        if (it[index] >= s.size()) {
            it[index] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void do_job(const std::string& s,
            const std::vector<std::size_t>& it)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != it.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << s[it[i]] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void cartesian_product(const std::string& s, std::size_t n)
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> it(n, 0u);

    do {
        do_job(s, it);
    } while (increase(s, it));
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Zqx5B9)